# Last record question on Access 2010 report

Tags: ms-access, visual-studio-2010

I haven't seen an answer addressing my specific issue.  I'm writing a report in Access 2010.  The data is grouped by State/County/Municipality.  In the detail section I'm looking to find the last record and based upon that record certain textboxes change.  As an example: On the last record the "name" is bolded.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: How are the records sorted? Can you use DMAX to find the last value in the sort field and then IF thisrecord.value = dmax result then bold ?

Comment: The records are sort by County (Group), Municipality (Group), and by Building Name.  I actually tried to create an specific index number for each building basically trying what you suggested.  It works for the first group but then bolds everything for every group thereafter.

Answer (score 0):

in the On_current event of the detail section you can do something like

```
if dmax("[Building name]","[tablename]","[Municipality]='"&me![Municipality])=me![Building name] then 
me![buildingname]/fontbold = true
end if
```

You'll need to tweak for your table  and control names